# ngTable with more than 10 columns displays incorrectly in chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, ngtable

I have a ngTable directive that works great when I have 10 or fewer columns, but as soon as I add in that eleventh one, the tables data labels are displayed in the wrong order, but not the data itself. Has anyone seen this before, and is there a solution or workaround?

Here is a plunker that shows exactly what I am seeing (you must view it in chrome it works in firefox, ie and safari)

http://plnkr.co/edit/Kxo4zGnwz0mYshbd2SET?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('main', ['ngTable'])
        .controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope, $filter, NgTableParams) {
            var data = [];
            for (var row = 1; row <= 15; row++) {
                var rowData = {};
                for (var col = 1; col <= 15; col++) {
                    rowData["col" + col] = "value" + col;
                }
                data.push(rowData);
            }


            $scope.cols = [];
            for(var column = 1; column <= 15; column++) {
                var columnDef = {
                    title: 'Column ' + column,
                    show: true,
                    field: 'col' + column
                };
                $scope.cols.push(columnDef);
            }

            $scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({
                page: 1, // show first page
                count: 10 // count per page
            }, {
                filterDelay: 0,
                total: data.length, // length of data
                getData: function($defer, params) {
                        var result = data;
                        var filteredData = params.filter() ?
                            $filter('filter')(result, params.filter()) :
                            result;
                        var orderedData = params.sorting() ?
                            $filter('orderBy')(filteredData, params.orderBy()) :
                            result;
                        params.total(orderedData.length);
                        $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
                }
            });
        });
```

the data labels that get moved, are the same every time regardless of content, and they get moved to the same spot. Thanks in advance